# How do I can save data downloaded from internet to internal device?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have this code:

```
struct ServerConnect {
    enum Result<T> {
        case succes(T)
        case error(String)
    }

    typealias completionHandler = (Result<Data >) -> ()

    func getJsonFromServer(parameters: String, completion: @escaping completionHandler) {
        let fullUrlString = ApiConstans.fullPath + parameters
        guard let url = URL(string: fullUrlString) else {
            debugPrint("\(ErrorsLabels.ServerConnect01)")
            return completion(.error("\(ErrorsLabels.ServerConnect01)"))
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {  (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                debugPrint("\(ErrorsLabels.ServerConnect02)")
                return completion(.error("\(ErrorsLabels.ServerConnect02)"))
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                debugPrint("\(ErrorsLabels.ServerConnect03)")
                return completion(.error("\(ErrorsLabels.ServerConnect03)"))
            }

            debugPrint("R> \(fullUrlString)")
            return completion(.succes(data))
            }.resume()
    }


    func getJsonProducts(lang: String?, region: Int?, completion: @escaping completionHandler) {
        self.getJsonFromServer(parameters: "?action=GET_PRODUCTS&lang=\(lang!)&region=\(region!)", completion: completion)
    }

}
```

I would like to save the downloaded data from the internet in the device's memory.

I'm trying this code:

```
getJsonProducts(lang: selectedLanguage, region: selectedRegion , completion: { (data) in
                    print("@@@@@ \(data)")
                     saveJsonFileToTheDisk(path: selectedLanguage + "/json/products.json",  downloadData: data)
                })

func saveJsonFileToTheDisk(path: String, downloadData: Data){
        do {
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(path)
            try downloadData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
        } catch { }
    }
```

But unfortunately it does not work. How can I make it work?

Below is an error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'ServerConnect.Result' to expected
>   argument type 'Data'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the definition of `getJsonProducts` method:

```
func getJsonProducts(lang: String?, region: Int?, completion: @escaping (Result<Data>) -> ()) {
```

The parameter `data` which is sent to `completion` block is actually of type `Result` containing the data, not the data itself. Thus, you should do:

```
getJsonProducts(lang: selectedLanguage, region: selectedRegion, completion: { result in
    switch result {
    case .succes(let data):
        saveJsonFileToTheDisk(path: selectedLanguage + "/json/products.json",  downloadData: data)
    case .error(let errorMessage):
        // Do something with the error message.
        break
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, the application starts, but does not save the file :(

Answer (score 0):

Your `completionHandler` from `getJsonProducts` returns a `Result<Data>`, not a simple `Data`, so you need to pattern match the `Result` instance, since it might not actually contain `Data`, it might contain a `String` error.

```
getJsonProducts(lang: selectedLanguage, region: selectedRegion , completion: { (data) in
    switch data {
        case let .succes(data):
            print("@@@@@ \(data)")
            saveJsonFileToTheDisk(path: selectedLanguage + "/json/products.json",  downloadData: data)
       case let .error(error):
            print(error)
    }
})
```